# 既存のhtaccessとwordpressのhtaccessを1つにしたい

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

既存のhtaccessとwordpressのhtaccessを1つにしたいです。
案件で、htaccessを1つにしなければいけない状況になりました。
ですが、htaccessがよくわかりません。

以下の２つのコードを1つにしていただきませんか？

### .htaccessコードその１

```
RewriteBase /
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test\.co.jp)(:80)? [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.test.co.jp/$1 [R=301,L]

# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
# RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.test.co.jp/$1 [R=301,L]

# Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.co.jp
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.test.co.jp/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^lab(.*)$ /mono/lab$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^oof(.*)$ /mono/oof$1 [L,R=301]
```

### .htaccessコードその2

```
# "BEGIN WordPress" から "END WordPress" までのディレクティブ (行) は
# 動的に生成され、WordPress フィルターによってのみ修正が可能です。
# これらのマーカー間にあるディレクティブへのいかなる変更も上書きされてしまいます。
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: マージするにもルールを決めないことにはマージできないと思います。

Comment: `.htaccess` はディレクトリごとに配置するファイルなので、このファイルだけでなく Wordpress とそれ以外のコンテンツとがどのように管理されていて、どのようにマージしたいのか、辺りも提示されていないと回答が難しそうです。

Comment: ワードプレスのURL変更でhtaccessファイル(.htaccessコードその2)をルートにアップロードする必要があります。
ですが、ルートには別のhtaccessファイル(.htaccessコードその１)があります。
上書きすると、既存のサイトが動かなくなる可能性があります。
なので、既存のhtaccessファイルとワードプレスのhtaccessファイルをマージする必要があります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: パッと見ただけでもlabやoofのリライトがwpのリライトに競合しそうです。新しいルールが必要そうです。